# Разделить фазеологизмы на группы

Tags: фразеология, учебное-задание

буря в стакане воды
в воде не тонет, в огне не горит
в рот воды набрать
вилами по воде
вода на чью-либо мельницу
водой не разольёшь
воды́ не замутит  
вывести на чистую воду
выйти сухим из воды
идти в огонь и в воду
как в воду глядеть
как в воду кануть
как воды в рот набрать
как две капли воды
как рыба в воде
как с гуся вода
концы в воду
ловить рыбу в мутной воде
много воды утекло с тех пор
мыть в семи водах

Нужно разделить на 4 группы: единства, сочетания, сращения, выражения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не могу дать 100% гарантии верности, потому что иногда мы субъективно понимаем степень спаянности.

Фразеологические единства: в рот воды набрать, вода на чью-либо мельницу, как в воду глядеть,  как две капли воды, как рыба в воде, как с гуся вода, как воды в рот набрать, идти в огонь и в воду, вывести на чистую воду, выйти сухим из воды.

Фразеологические сочетания: воды́ не замутит, буря в стакане воды.

Фразеологические сращения: вилами по воде, концы в воду, водой не разольёшь, как в воду кануть.

Фразеологические выражения: ловить рыбу в мутной воде, много воды утекло с тех пор, мыть в семи водах; в воде не тонет, в огне не горит.

Answer (score 0):

Это сравнения, наставления, описания, преувеличения. В основном из известных присказок и поговорок. Здесь правда вопроса не было, так это классификация по принципу действия, не философская.